# FirebaseStorage Url to Imageview Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I've successfully uploaded images to my FirebaseStorage, but I'm facing an issue putting into imageview. Below are my codes ideas came from [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585334/tasksnapshot-getdownloadurl-method-not-working/56940283) I can't seems to know what I've wrong. Much guidance appreciated.

```
mUploadTask = ref.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // Image uploaded successfully
                // Dismiss dialog
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Task<Uri> result = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();
                result.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        String imageUrl = uri.toString();
                        Glide.with(CreateStory.this)
                                .load(new File(imageUrl)) // Uri of the picture
                                .into(mIvImage);

                added ........
               Log.w(TAG, "results... = " + imageUrl);
                    }
                });


                Toast.makeText(CreateStory.this, "Image Uploaded!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

the log file as below, is not null and is returning the Url from firebase Storage url
        results... = https://private...images%2Fdca96752-beeb-4331-8de0-1ad413b89b74?alt=media&token=98f30bec-aaa7-4bbc-ba29-09c761d68cae

Comment: Glide.with(CreateStory.this).load(imageUrl).into(mIvImage); Why do you set like this.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir my intention was image will show after uploading completed. Am I doing wrong? much guidance appreciated

Comment: You are doing right. load(imageUrl) is enough for you

Comment: Also getMetadata()  is not necessary

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir after few round of testing, but it always shows blank, Did i do something wrong?

Comment: I don't know why getmetada(). Did you run debug mode. Is imageUrl null?

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir I have added a log to get result, but it seems is not null

Comment: then you can try .load(imageUrl)

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir It worked like a charm, you are my life saver. One more thing, as you mentioned "getMetadata() is not necessary " does it mean i should remove it?

Comment: You can remove it. no problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @KasımÖzdemir guidance, I've successfully achieved my goal. He/she also corrected my code as well. Kindly refer to below working code. Cheers :)

```
       mUploadTask = ref.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // Image uploaded successfully
                // Dismiss dialog
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {

                        // get firebase storage url
                        String profileImageUrl = task.getResult().toString();
                        Glide.with(CreateStory.this).load(profileImageUrl).into(mIvImage);
                        Log.w(TAG, "image url = " + profileImageUrl + " | imageUri = " + imageUri);
                    }
                });

                Toast.makeText(CreateStory.this, "Image Uploaded!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
```