# Can i fetch an Image from storage using this Firebase function call?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

This is the function I'm using to upload image in `Firebase` Storage but at the same time I'm returning image url too.

```
Future<String> updateUserData(Project project) async {
    firestoreInstance.collection('projects').add(
      {
        'id': project.id,
        'title': project.title,
        'description': project.description,
        'duration': project.duration,
        'members': project.members,
        'complexity': project.complexity,
        'affordability': project.affordability,
        'prequisites': project.prequisites,
        'contact': project.contact,
        
      },
    );

     fileName = basename(project.image.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
        
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(project.image);
    taskSnapshot=await uploadTask.onComplete;
    downloadUrl =  taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().toString();
        return downloadUrl;
  }
   
   String returnUrl(){
     return downloadUrl;
   }
```

Here I'm calling the function to return the `url` but it is returning `null`, need help figuring this out.

```
child: Image.network(database.returnUrl().toString()
                      ,
                      height: 100,
                      width: 80,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      alignment: Alignment.center),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would've added this a comment, unfortunately I cannot.

You need to make sure that when `updateUserData()` returns, that you assign it's value to the `downloadUrl` variable, simply returning it in this way won't work. I don't know if you have any other code for this, but from what you've shown, you need something like this.

```
//Maybe have this set to a default profile URL, incase something goes wrong?
String downloadUrl="";

Future<void> updateUserData(Project project) async {
    firestoreInstance.collection('projects').add(
      {
        'id': project.id,
        'title': project.title,
        'description': project.description,
        'duration': project.duration,
        'members': project.members,
        'complexity': project.complexity,
        'affordability': project.affordability,
        'prequisites': project.prequisites,
        'contact': project.contact,
      },
    );

     fileName = basename(project.image.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =

        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(project.image);
    taskSnapshot=await uploadTask.onComplete;
    downloadUrl =  taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().toString();

  }

   String returnUrl(){
    //You probably don't need this now, as you can access downloadURL directly.
     return downloadUrl;
   }
```

Then in your image:

```
Image.network(downloadUrl ...
 //The rest of your styling
);
```

Hopefully this makes sense. Basically, you can't access another function's variable from another function.

Either that or I'm completely wrong, but as I said, I don't see `downloadUrl` being defined anywhere.

Comment: its returning empty string now,idk why its not getting the urlLink     https://github.com/Himanshuranjan30/projfirebase (My Project link) give it a check plese,Thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm this line: downloadUrl =  taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().toString(); is not returning nothing?

Comment: Also seems like taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().toString(); is deprecated you can check details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585334/tasksnapshot-getdownloadurl-method-not-working/56940283

Comment: @HarifVelarde the solution seems not to work with dart flutter

Comment: finally solved,it was me doing a silly mistake with provider. Thank you guys for all the help.